# Deploying to Tomcat root using Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, java, deployment, jenkins

Is there any way to deploy my Java application .war file **at root** on Tomcat 7 server, using the [Deploy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin) for Jenkins?

Currently the app gets deployed at `http://server/foo/` if it comes in a file named `foo.war`.

Comment: (Also, is there a Stack Exchange site where this question would  belong better?)

Comment: For now, I used this workaround: move `webapps/ROOT` to another name; do the deployment via Jenkins by executing a shell script that copies the war file under webapps **with the name `ROOT.war`**. Anyway, I'll leave the question open; it would be nice (and less of a hack) to be able to do this with the Deploy plugin.

Comment: Why don't you just generate a war file with the name ROOT.war?

Comment: @DoubleMalt: Good point... If that works with the Deploy plugin too, I'm going to feel a little stupid. I'll try it when back at work (in a few weeks).

Comment: @Jonik Did you get this to work ? I am tryign to deploy my ROOT.war to tomcat using jenkins. And its not working.

Comment: @NimChimpsky, sorry, I still haven't tried deploying "ROOT.war" through the Jenkins Deploy plugin...

Comment: @Jonik didn't work for me. And when I rename ROOT.war to something else it succeeds but then does not start the app http://stackoverflow.com/q/9002122/106261 ... ?  But you did succesfully deploy with jenkins using FOO.war ?

Comment: It's been a while, but yeah, as I wrote in the question: "the app gets deployed at `http://server/foo/` if it comes in a file named `foo.war`"

Comment: Why not allow it to sit at /foo/ then use apache to reverse-proxy it, and rewrite it to /

Answer (score -2):

Overly simple solution for any problem such as this:

Set your appBase for the host container to the path you want.  (Make sure to turn off autodeploy, etc.)

Comment: I changed appBase (with help from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html)) but that doesn't seem to work. That changes the dir under which Tomcat looks for apps to deploy, **but the app still gets deployed at `http://server/foo`**. Also, this breaks `http://server/manager/text/list` that the Deploy plugin depends upon.